# What's wrong with the SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a code to check if the stored procedure with some specified name has already been deployed or not. The code is

```
protected virtual async Task<bool?> IsProcedureDeployed(string storedProcedureName)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandText = "select count(*) from sysobjects where type = 'P' and name = @storedProcedureName",
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout
                };

                await this.EnsureConnectionOpened();
                int count = (int)(await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync());

                return count > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.SqlConnection.Close();
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

this.EnsureConnectionOpened looks like this:

```
protected async Task EnsureConnectionOpened()
        {
            if (SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed && SqlTransaction == null)
            {
                await SqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            }
        }
```

and when it comes to the execution of `int count = (int)(await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync());` it always throws an exception which says... "Invalid operation. The connection is closed.". I have checked the state of SqlConnection, and it is Open! What the hell am I doing wrong?

EDIT. Every SqlCommand must have a SqlConnection and properly setted parameters (if needed). The final version is

```
protected virtual async Task<bool?> IsProcedureDeployed(string storedProcedureName)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sysobjects where type = 'P' and name = @storedProcedureName", this.SqlConnection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout
                };

                SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@storedProcedureName",
                    Value = storedProcedureName
                };

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

                await this.EnsureConnectionOpened();
                int count = (int)(await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync());

                return count > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.SqlConnection.Close();
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped into `EnsureConnectionOpened` to verify that it's entering the block that calls `OpenAsync`? Also, are you sharing this helper class with other threads? Helper classes like this almost always manage connections poorly. Connections are pooled. It's okay to create and dispose connection *objects* in local scope.

Comment: Are you setting your `SqlCommand.SqlConnection` property?

Comment: @madreflection Yes. It stepped in the `EnsureConnectionOpened` and didn't do at all because I have previously opened the SqlConnection.

Comment: You should use using blocks in order to properly dispose connections after they are closed.

Comment: Well your not setting the connection to your command...., you aren't doing anything but constructing a command...

Comment: @LaughingVergil silly me, I haven't pointed the SqlConnection to this SqlCommand)

Comment: So the lesson here is to create (and dispose) your connection in local scope, and call `connection.CreateCommand()` so that you get a command with the connection already assigned to it.

Comment: TBH, if you debugged what `sqlCommand` was on `await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync()`, you would notice it would be `null`... I know you mentioned it said it was open, but that's not the case; your `EnsureConnectionOpened` is flawed.

Comment: @madreflection `EnsureConnectionOpened` is only being used in this class)

Comment: That may be, but the object doesn't need to exist at the class level. Method level is sufficient and you can locally ensure that you're using it properly.

Comment: You need to get all your sql stuff in the same place. Having a class level connection is not the right way to handle them at all. You need to close and dispose your connections immediately after use. Read bout and start utilizing the USING statement. Also, your query has a parameter but your command does not.

Comment: You would get a lot of upvotes if you posted the correct way to do this. Some good insight the comments...hint hint

Comment: @Train take it)

Comment: Set the `DataType` and `Size/Length` of the parameter, use `using` statements etc... If `await this.EnsureConnectionOpened();` fails, then calling `this.SqlConnection.Close();` in the catch is useless... better than before though :)

Comment: @SeanLange well why not? Why does some other class need to take care of handling connections? They can be managed in one place if needed (e.g. your Business Logic classes don't have to work with the database management, it may be up to your Data Access Layer classes). Btw I totally agree on your statement on USNIG, it's better to use it than dispose Connections/Commands manually.

Comment: Because if you leave your connection object floating around it will consume connections from the connection pool. I did not state you should handle connection in another class. They should be handled directly in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rework this method a bit. Get all your connection stuff in the same place instead of spread all over the place. Also, since your posted code was only using the try/catch to close the connection (and rethrow the exception) I removed it entirely. You don't need any error handling here. Let the exception happen and bubble up to the calling method. I am guessing this logic is in your data layer?

Something like this is contained nice and tidy.

```
protected virtual async Task<bool?> IsProcedureDeployed(string storedProcedureName)
{
    bool IsDeployed = false;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sysobjects where type = 'P' and name = @storedProcedureName", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@storedProcedureName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = storedProcedureName; //using nvarchar(128) because object names use sysname which is a synonym for nvarchar(128)
            var result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            bool.TryParse(result.ToString(), out IsDeployed);
        }
    }
    return IsDeployed;
}
```